# adding a jsPDF font?

Tags: jspdf

I found some information on the Internet, but it works. I get errors when I add my own font. Here the error.

```
Function Error output@file:///C:/Users/jspdf.debug.js line 1449 > srcScript : 1985: 87: string contains invalid character
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe share the section of your code where you add the font, it's hard to give an answer from the error.

But normally you add a font by converting a tff file to a base64 string and adding it like this:

```js
doc.addFileToVFS('font-name.ttf', base64StringOfTffFile);
doc.addFont('font-name.ttf', 'font-name', 'normal');
doc.setFont('font-name', 'normal');
```